# Spring/Mongo grouping count() return 0 if nothing on that day

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I have a query that does the following collapse on tDate and counts the number of relevant results on a particular day (tDate).

```
Aggregation.group("tDate").count().as("total")
```

However, I want to have days without any counts to return as 0. What's the best way to return 0 if count() is empty for the tDate?

Comment: The best way is to "post process" your results and simply insert `0` counts into the array of responses where the day was not present. Whilst it is possible to "brute force" the aggregation pipeline into generating output for each day in a range, it is not recommended since it would place a much larger load on the server than would be necessary. Also the same kind of "brute force" can be applied to "squashing the results into a single document" and applying the range, but again this is not recommended and the pipeline instructions are far more terse than the client code required to do it.

Comment: Also note any "brute force" requires features available only in the MongoDB 3.4 server. So unless you have the latest version, it's not even possible at all. But you should not do it anyway. Alter returned results in the client code, since it's a lot more simple to do so.